# propertyplaceholderconfigurer class name substitution problem

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

The following example works for "class name substitution using the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer":

http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=228136&postcount=2

However, when porting this code over (messages.properties, com.spring.ioc.TestClass, and spring-config.xml) to a web application, the class name substitution now fails.

I am running on the webapp on Tomcat through the Eclipse plugin. In the web.xml I have the following:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The following is output in the log:

```
282  [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - 
Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'test'
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [${test.class}] for bean with name 'test' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${test.class}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1141)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1177)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:222)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:505)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:362)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${test.class}
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
 at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:211)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:385)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1138)
 ... 23 more
```

I haven't included it, but the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is successfully locating the `messages.properties` file, but this seems to happen *after* the above error is output.

Does anybody know why this is the case and how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: We'll need to see your `spring-config.xml`

Comment: Where is your properties file located? make sure it is under WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Hi. The spring-config.xml is exactly the same from the example given in the springsource weblink I gave. The properties file is in Web-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem using Spring batch. The BeanFactory try to load the class before than the substitution occurs for the classname. 
I ended by not using substitution for classname because it is not a strong requirement for me. 
You may try to:

- extend the Bean Factory in order to skip class with variable non substituted
- extend the Bean Factory in order to load your place holder at the very first (since lazy-init and depends-on propertyPlaceOrder fail as well)

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't included it, but the
>   PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is
>   successfully locating the
>   messages.properties file, but this
>   seems to happen after the above error
>   is output.

I strongly belive the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is not working! (If it is not configured it can't.)

Add the configuer to your spring configuration.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:messages.properties"/>
```